# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id') when trying to create

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm making a public prayer journal, where you can also add favorite Bible verses, in full stack. Whenever I try to add a prayer (or a verse) I get this error: "caught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')".

```
useEffect(() => {
    getPrayers().then(setPrayer);
    if (object.id) setFormInput(object);
  }, [object]);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setFormInput((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [name]: value,
    }));
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (object.id) {
      updatePrayer(formInput, object.id)
        .then(() => router.push('/prayers'));
    } else {
      const payload = { ...formInput };
      createPrayer(payload).then(setFormInput(initialState));
    }
  };
```

I have tried changing user.id to user.uid, as well as change uid to user

```
const createPrayer = (prayerObj, user) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const prayer = {
    content: prayerObj.content,
    publication_date: prayerObj.pub_date,
    uid: user.id,
  };
  fetch(`${dbUrl}/prayers`, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(prayer),
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  })
    .then((response) => resolve(response.json()))
    .catch((error) => reject(error));
});
```

Comment: In which line does the error occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best to show where the error is coming from, however I assume it is this function:

```
const createPrayer = (prayerObj, user) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const prayer = {
    content: prayerObj.content,
    publication_date: prayerObj.pub_date,
    uid: user.id,
  };
  fetch(`${dbUrl}/prayers`, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(prayer),
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  })
    .then((response) => resolve(response.json()))
    .catch((error) => reject(error));
});
```

Here you are setting `uid: user.id`, user is a param of the function but is not supplied here     `createPrayer(payload).then(setFormInput(initialState));`

Hence user is undefined, which is your error.

To go into a bit more detail so you understand the error next time (it is fairly common)

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'property') when trying to create

an object in js is {}. Anything you put inside an object is a property so:

```js
const obj = {
  property: "value"
}
```

so the error cannot read properties of undefined (reading property) is saying obj is not defined so I cannot get the value of property.